# MongoDB update outter and array-embedded document atomically

Tags: mongodb

I have an object in the `cart` collection:

```
{
    _id: 1,
    purchased: 0,
    items: [
    {
        item_id: 5,
        count: 0
    },
    {
        item_id: 6,
        count: 0
    },
   ]

}
```

And I would like to atomically increment both `purchased` and `count` of item_id: 6. I believe the correct update command is:

```
db.carts.update({_id: 1, "items.item_id": 6}, 
{
    $inc: {
        purchased: 1
        "items.$.count": 1
    } 
})
```

This seems to work in the console but I am not sure if this is 100% correct. Can anyone spot any issues with this update command or confirm this is correct for my use case?

For scaling this to my app, suppose `_id` is an ObjectId and `item_id` is also ObjectId (ie they are unique).

Comment: Yes it is correct. But you could also use `$elemMatch` in the query object. `db.carts.find({"_id":1,"items":{$elemMatch:{"item_id":6}}},{..})`.

Comment: Thanks! What's the benefit of using elemMatch?

Comment: It is used when you want to match multiple criteria for a document in an array. Unless that is your intention, your approach is the way to go. - http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#update-embedded-documents-using-multiple-field-matches. I have edited my previous comment too. We can discuss more here if need be - http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70508/mongodb